# How to remove complete RVM from system with .bashrc and .bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have some issue with my current RVM. I am not able to upgrade it and also not able to install new ruby version. I am also not able to install new gems in my system as on bundle install it returns rubygems error(getaddrinfo-error).

Please suggest me right direction to remove it and reinstall it safely.

Thanks

Comment: We need to know more about your RVM environment. Please add the output of `rvm info` to your question by updating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rvm implode
```

From the [rvm 'documentation'](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm):

> (seppuku) removes the rvm installation completely.
>
> This means everything in $rvm_path (~/.rvm || /usr/local/rvm).
>
> This does not touch your profiles. However, this means that you must
>   manually clean up your profiles and remove the lines which source RVM.

So I'd say you execute `rvm implode` and then remove every rvm related line you inserted in `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Type these commands:

```
cd ~
rm -rf .rvm
```

Those will move you to your home directory, and remove the current ~/.rvm directory.

At that point, you can reinstall RVM without needing to remove the initializers from your .bashrc or .bash_profile files.

It's important to understand [RVM's installation process](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), so I strongly suggest you read through that document before you reinstall.

Comment: better use `rvm implode` if possible. as rvm might be installed in `/usr/local/rvm` or other places.

Comment: If it's in /usr/local/rvm, `rvm implode` won't solve the problem.